# invalid Firebase binding source when trying to use readyCallback with vuefire

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuefire

This is my first time using Vuefire. I want to render some data after the data is loaded using `db.ref('page_data')`. In the docs, I have read that you can use a function inside of `firebase: {}` to have a callback when its ready called `readyCallback: function(){}`

but for some weird reason when I use this firebase throws an error:

`invalid Firebase binding source`

My `<script>` tag looks like this

```js
import { db } from "./firebase"

export default {
    name: 'App',
    firebase: { 
      data: db.ref('page_data'),
      readyCallback: function(){
        console.log("Ready!")
      }
    },
    data(){
        return{
            data: ui_data,
        }
    }
}
```

If i remove `readyCallback` no errors are shown, but the problem is that if i try to render the data before the request is finished the vue app errors out on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readyCallback` should be nested inside:

```
 firebase: { 
  data: {
    source: db.ref('page_data'),
    readyCallback: function(){
      console.log("Ready!")
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Thank you, i somehow missed that.